# Using TfsDeployer to send notifications when work item is added - TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have `TFSDeployer` (from Codeplex) installed on our TFS server that facilitates sending notifications when a build quality changes.

Can we use it to send notifications when work items are added/edited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS does send notifications when work items are edited/added. 
Team Explorer >> Right Click on Project Name >> Alerts Explorer
... allows you to define a rule to send yourself e-mail messages when your work items are changed.

If you install TFS Power Tools you get an Alerts Explorer screen, which is located in Visual Studio's "Team" menu. Alerts Explorer allows you to define much more complex rules for e-mail notifications. And also you can send mail to more than one person.